# How to get first and last value by same item in sequence, with possibility of the same item occurring again

Tags: sql-server, query

Similar to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214915/how-to-get-last-and-first-occurrence-of-items-into-separated-columns) but with the possibility that the same name can appear again in the following rows.

I have this table:

```
id name     value
1  Daniel   3
2  Daniel   7
3  Daniel   2
4  Carol    9
5  Carol    4
6  Carol    9
7  Ray      5
8  Charles  1
9  Daniel   6
10 Daniel   5
11 Daniel   5
```

I would like to get the first and the last value (ordered by `id`) in a table like:

```
name    value_1st  value_last
Daniel  3         2
Carol   9         9  
Ray     5         5
Charles 1         1
Daniel  6         5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, 
                 CASE WHEN name = LAG(name) OVER (ORDER BY id) 
                      THEN 0 
                      ELSE 1 
                      END the_same
          FROM test ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *, SUM(the_same) OVER (ORDER BY id) group_num
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT DISTINCT
       name, 
       FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY group_num ORDER BY id) value_1st,
       FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY group_num ORDER BY id DESC) value_last 
FROM cte2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=7a6fbd208d2dae006f87f093c2d688a9)

Answer (score -1):

SELECT s.name,(CASE WHEN s.name =t.name THEN MAX(s.id) END) AS 'value_1st',(CASE WHEN s.name=t.name AND  s.id =MAX(s.id) THEN s.value END) AS 'value_last'
FROM tableA s,(SELECT distinct name FROM tableA)t
WHERE s.name = t.name

Comment: Syntax error guaranteed. Not full grouping.